# ggplot: stacking graphs with x-axis labels only on bottom graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6")
group <- c("Cats", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs")
value <- c(5, 10, 20, 5, 15, 30)

data <- data.frame(ID, group, value)
```

When I graph it using this code

```
ggplot(data, aes(group, value, color=group)) + geom_jitter(show.legend = FALSE) + labs(x = " ") +
  theme_bw(base_size=20) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

I get this result

[image]

I have a couple dataframes that I want to graph together, but when I use `grid.arrange` I get a result that has the x-axis labeled on both graphs:

[image]

Since the x-axis is the same, my desired output has the x-axis labeled only on the bottom graph, like this:

[image]

Is this possible in ggplot?

Comment: If they have the same axes - then the data can probably be in the same `data.frame` and you can `facet_grid` a single plot: e.g. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html

Comment: Certainly possible to use `theme` to turn off axis labels etc by setting `axis.text.x = element_blank()` but facet_wrap is much easier

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could bind the data frames together and then use `facet_grid`

```
ID <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6")
group <- c("Cats", "Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs")
value <- c(5, 10, 20, 5, 15, 30)
value2 <- c(8, 13, 23, 8, 18, 50)

data <- data.frame(ID, group, value, whichdf = "1")
data2 <-data.frame(ID, group, value = value2, whichdf = "2") 

df <- rbind(data,data2)

ggplot()

ggplot(df, aes(group, value, color=group)) + 
  facet_grid(vars(whichdf)) +
  geom_jitter(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  labs(x = " ") +
  theme_bw(base_size=20) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

Which yields

[image]

If the y-axis values vary greatly, you can specify  `scales = "free"` within `facet_grid` for each plot to have their own y-axis scale.